# Traversing DOM and inserting a value into <input/>

Tags: jquery, insert, traversal

It would be a lot of code to copy paste, so here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyka88/5WQgc/19/)

Focus on any input, buttons appear:

```
$('input').focus(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
       $this.closest('p').after($( ".specialCharactersWrap" ));

    });
```

then click, the button's text gets inserted into the input:

```
 $('.specialCharactersWrap button').click(function() {
         var $this = $(this);
    var value = $(this).text();
    var input = $('.FillIn .FillInInput');
    input.val(input.val() + value);
    return false;
});
```

Problem: it inserts into **ALL** inputs. I need it to insert into **one single**  above (which is focused). Tried traversing the DOM with `closest()`, but it doesn't work, it breaks, my failed attempt here ===> [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andreyka88/5WQgc/18/)

how do I get the button text into one single input in focus? What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Guys, the answers are all equally clear + useful + working. I voted everyone up, thank you. But I have to choose only one answer. I'm choosing Felix's because it was the closest to what I was trying to do. Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/5WQgc/21/)

```
var $that = this // here my change
       $('input').focus(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
           $that = $(this);// here my change
       $this.closest('p').after($( ".specialCharactersWrap" ));
       // alert('test');

    });
     $('.specialCharactersWrap button').click(function() {
         var $this = $(this);
    var value = $(this).text();
    var input = $that;// here my change
    input.val(input.val() + value);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: After trying to put several <input>s into one <p> I realised that the function inserts button text into ALL <input>s of that <p>. Your solution doesn't. So it's the best one that works for me, thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to change

```
var input = $('.FillIn .FillInInput');
```

to:

```
var input = $(this).closest('.specialCharactersWrap').prev().find('.FillInInput');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5WQgc/20/)**

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
$('input').focus(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
       $this.closest('p').after($( ".specialCharactersWrap" ));
        $('.FillInInput').closest('p').removeClass('focussed');
        $this.closest('p').addClass('focussed');
       // alert('test');

    });
     $('.specialCharactersWrap button').click(function() {
         var $this = $(this);
    var value = $(this).text();
    var input = $('.FillIn').find('.focussed').find('.FillInInput');

    input.val(input.val() + value);
    return false;
});
```

I have added one class on input focus and then use it on button click
Or you can also user .prev()